# Deep Q Learning Network converging behavior is strange

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I have implemented a deep q learning network (from the orginal paper without any subsequent modification and improvement) to train an agent playing tic-tac-toe. My hyper parameters are as follows:

Network Structure: 3 layer MLP with 1 hidden layer(150 nodes)

Input: The input is of shape (9,) with possible value [1,0,-1] representing a board state

Output: The output is of shape (9,) with possible value [0,1] represent possible action

Reward: if win then 10 , if lose then -10 , if draw then 0
Gamma(discount for future reward):0.99

epislon(for exploration): initially 0.3, then decreases linearly with respect to the number of episodes

Replay memory:2000000 so stored samples will never  be replaced by new samples(beacues the memory will never be full)

Gradiant Descent Method: Momentum SGD

Loss function : square(y-x)

I use random walk as the exploring strategy in epsilon function and use this srategy to simulate the opponent's walk.

I then use the win rate of most recently perceived 200 games in the training process to evaluate the model's strength.

The training process is above avergage at beginning, the win rate raises from around 0.4 to around 0.70 and stay there for quite a lot of episodes( slowly raises to around 0.78).

However, at some point (about 30000 episodes), the win rate dramatically decreases and drops to 0.6 rapidly (and stays there).

Could anyone possibly give me some guidance about why this decay happens?

I made some modification:

1. Decreased the replay memory size to 100000,the replay memory size seems not    the reason why the collapse happens according to experiments.
2. Increased the minibatch size sampled from the replay memory.

I am running another experiment. So far the winning rate does not collapse
Here's the curves:(left figure is the winning rate and right figure is the loss for the Q value)

The behavior mention above finally happened again:

[Smooth Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBIrk.png)

Is there any reason why this happens?

Final results:

[Final resuts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvQlF.png)

Comment: you did not provide much details about what happens besides testing - what about fitting errors? It looks like your learning diverged, which can happen for many reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the response!In a general supervised ML scenario it is possible to measure the level of fit using some method, for example KFold cross validation to measure the level of fit, because in that scenario data set can be divided into independent training sets and testing sets. But I don't know how to do this in the learning procedure of deep q learning network , the data are generated during training procedure，and all data are necessary for training(each of them represents a policy or strategy), so I don't know how to get  independent  testing sets for cross validation. Any suggestions?

Comment: what I meant is keeping track of the loss for the Q values, since this is what you are actually optimising. of course as you said these are not iid samples etc. so the loss does not have to go down, but it is worth looking at its behaviour during training.

Comment: OK，thanks for your suggestion.I'll plot the loss for the Q values and post it afterwards.

Comment: @lejlot Hello, I posts the figure of the loss of Q-values , it drops down and stays stable at some value and starting to go up and down after 500000 episodes. It seems when the winning rate starts to drop down, the loss for Q-values stay at relatively high levels.